# How to change User Agent in YQL?

Tags: yql

I am trying to change User-Agent using code in this data table sample: https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/blob/master/data/data.headers.xml

```
req = y.rest(url);
req.header('User-Agent', ua);
```

But it seems not work, my server receive the Http Header: `YahooCacheSystem`.

Is it possible change UA in YQL?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the user agent by passing the `ua` parameter, e.g.:

```
use "<your_table_execute_key>" as data_headers; select * from data_headers where url="http://www.amazon.com/" and ua="Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1"
```

With this said, it doesn’t appear that passing the UA makes a difference in the HTML content that is returned, at least for Amazon using the sample query above – I was expecting to get the mobile version by passing the iPhone UA string, but that was not the case.

UPDATE: Passing the iPhone UA string worked for http://www.yahoo.com/ (I got the mobile version), so maybe it didn’t work for Amazon because it requires another HTTP header that we’re not setting for mobile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What is `Keep in mind that the open table you're using is to get the server's headers, not set them.` means? What's the different while set `ua` or not?

Comment: @andyf I think I misunderstand your question, so that's why I included that statement. Thanks for clarifying; I have removed it and added a note on the `ua` param from my own experience after having just tried it now.

Comment: Thanks for your update. Maybe it only works on services provided by Yahoo.